# mysql issue with auto increment

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a mysql database which has the following tables:

```
create table post
(
id int primary key auto_increment,
group_id int,
post varchar(2000),
person_id int,
foreign key(person_id) references person(person_id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
foreign key(group_id) references groups(group_id) on update cascade on delete cascade
);
create table comment
(
id int primary key auto_increment,
p_id int,
person_id int,
comment varchar(2000),
foreign key(p_id) references post(id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
foreign key(person_id) references person(person_id) on update cascade on delete cascade
);
```

Here the post id and comment id are not getting incremented properly. I created and dropped these tables many times and every time it takes the initial id as some random value and each of the insert takes any random value.

For eg. it takes 552 sometimes and sometimes as 3.

I also checked the following on mysql command line:

```
show variables like 'auto_inc%';
```

and both the values auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset are set to 1.

Any help on this is appreciated as this is holding critical biz work.

Comment: Please show your insert statement after which you have described behaviour

Comment: I am giving insert statement as below: INSERT INTO post (group_id,post,person_id) VALUES (1,'Manchester United won by 5-0 against Bayern',1);

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem because your insert statements reference two other tables (`person` and `groups`) which are not shown in your code (so I have no idea what's going with those tables).

But, since you wrote

> Any help on this is appreciated as this is holding critical biz work.

... here's some help / suggestions:

I'm not sure how those tables are being *successfully* created because I get a lot of errors when I try that code (but that's beside the point), however here's a more efficient method (**Note**: I can only assume the references to the tables `person` and `groups` means that those
tables already exist):

**EDIT**: Try this first, after creating the tables:

```
FLUSH TABLES;
ALTER TABLE `comment` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE `post` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

If that doesn't help, here's the more efficient method as mentioned above:

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `p_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `person_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `p_id` (`p_id`),
  KEY `person_id` (`person_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `person_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
  KEY `person_id` (`person_id`)
);

ALTER TABLE `comment`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `comment_fk_1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`p_id`)
  REFERENCES `post` (`id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `comment`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `comment_fk_2`
  FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`)
  REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `post`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `post_fk_1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`)
  REFERENCES `comment` (`person_id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `post`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `post_fk_2`
  FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`)
  REFERENCES `groups` (`group_id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: I tried the first option and did not work. the second option too is not working... For some weird reason it is taking random numbers :(